# accessing files in a particular folder in a window application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to select multiple files based on their specific contents from a particular folder and edit their contents. I am using winform in C#.

any idea which are the classes that can be used.

It would be helpful if code given for example.

thanks.

Comment: You want to pre-select the folders for further selection, or just grab everything under `C:\myDir` that has the word 'kittens` inside of the file? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx

Comment: no..i just want to select files from specific folder only ..no need to pre select it..I can give direct path of the folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to get to the names of the files in a directory. If they're text files you can read them via [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=VS.80).aspx) (returnsan array of strings, one per line of the file) or [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=VS.80).aspx) (returns a single string containing the entire content of the file).

To save the edited files have a look at [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=VS.80).aspx) or [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=VS.80).aspx).

Comment: As far as I know a folder **is** a directory, the words are just synonyms.